# I am seeing this error "Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'."

Tags: flutter

I have run flutter upgrade after that it told me to Flutter App Migration from Previous Version (Android Embedding V2), and after doing it, I am seeing this error.

Error image

[image]

error message

```
[FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: You must be getting some additional errors as well can you post that

Comment: no just this error i am getting